# Cheapest way from Frankfurt Hahn to Wiesbaden?

Tags: public-transport, germany, airport-transfer, hhn

What is a cheapest way to go from Frankfurt Hahn Airport to Wiesbaden main station by public transport?

And vice versa.

Comment: Hitch hiking, not the way I would but I bet you do not have to pay nor will it take forever. (If you want a useful answer, you have to restrict the question quite a bit more.)

Comment: @Willeke thank you for your comment. Hitch hiking it's good way for me, but I mean public transport.

Comment: Hahn is in the middle of nowhere, and there is no good way to get to the real Frankfurt. Even in a car it is 90 minutes. Basically, calling Hahn ‘Frankfurt’ is cheat.

Comment: @Aganju What's bad about the bus?

Comment: @Researcher The best way would be the Flibco bus to Mainz, which costs 5 euros, then the S8 suburban train to Wiesbaden (three stops, costing 2.80 euros). The bus ticket can be bought here https://www.flibco.com/en#/booking

Comment: @Coke many thanks! But I only found tickets for 13.50 euros from Hahn to Mainz Hbf. Is it ok or I missed something I don't know ?)

Comment: @Researcher It says "from €5" but I checked closer now and you're right. However, this is the only realistic route by public Transport. You could try "blackriding" by getting a ticket to Ingelheim (which sometimes costs €5) and remaining onboard until Mainz (one stop's difference) - has worked very well for me but I can't give any guarantees

Comment: @Researcher When (date, time) are you landing in Hahn, and when do you have to be back at the Airport?

Comment: @Coke thanks man!) I'll be in Hahn in two weeks(still have no tickets). But I've checked even for December and ticket still costs 13.50 euros. Thank you for your tips!

Comment: @Researcher The bus stops at the Mainz train station, so you can conveniently access the S8 train from there